# Can I Convert A Byte() to a string?

Tags: vb.net

I need a solution to my current code, I am trying to save text to a file from a Text Box, and add a string to it.
My following code is:

```
 Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(fileName.Text)

    ' Add text to the file. 

    Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(CodeBox.Text)

    Dim Code = "-- Made with LUA Creator by Sam v1.9
    " + info
    fs.Write(Code, 0, Code.Length)
    fs.Close()

    MsgBox("File saved as " + fileName.Text)
```

But Visual Studio says that I cannot use "+" operator with strings & bytes:

Error   BC30452 Operator '+' is not defined for types 'String' and 'Byte()'.

Anyone have a solution?
Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find it anywhere here so I just asked myself. Thanks.

Comment: `&` is for string concatenation; `+` is for addition. Try concatenating your string with the TextBox, before using`GetBytes`: `"-- Made with..." & CodeBox.Text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can I Convert A Byte() to a string?" Short answer is yes, but that doesn't look like what you're really wanting to do.

You're trying to concatenate a `String` with a `Byte` array, which `Dim Code` has no idea what the end result is supposed to be.

`FileStream.Write()` requires a `Byte` array so you can try a couple of things

1. Concatenate the string from the TextBox with your "header" information then turn it into a `Byte` array.

   ```
   Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(fileName.Text)

   ' Add text to the file. 
   Dim Code As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("-- Made with LUA Creator by Sam v1.9 " & CodeBox.Text)
   fs.Write(Code, 0, Code.Length)
   fs.Close()
   ```
2. Write your "header" information, then write the Textbox information

   ```
   Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(fileName.Text)

   ' Add text to the file. 
   Dim header As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("-- Made with LUA Creator by Sam v1.9 ")
   Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(CodeBox.Text)
   fs.Write(header, 0, header.Length)
   fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
   fs.Close()
   ```

Comment: I got it to work, I used #1 only and it worked, thanks.

Comment: @samiles1995 You're welcome... Kindly give my answer a check mark so your question is solved.